# How do you handle PropertyChange for a boolean value?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program in which I have a publicly defined boolean value

```
Public boolOverallStatus As Boolean = True
```

and I need to execute some code whenever the boolean value changes. In previous applications, an actual form item change handled this, but it can be changed by several different subs.

How would I handle this? I'm looking through msdn, but it's rather confusing. 
In a nutshell: How to execute code when the event of a boolean value changing occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it a property instead.

```
Private _boolOverallStatus As Boolean = True

Property boolOverallStatus As Boolean
  Get
    Return _boolOverallStatus
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value as Boolean)
    If value <> _boolOverallStatus Then
      _boolOverallStatus = value
      '// handle more code changes here.'
    End If
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Perfect! I handled the rest with some if then IfElse magic!

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following pattern which resembles what Microsoft do for most of their Changed events.

```
Class MyClass

    Public Property OverallStatus As Boolean
        Get
            Return _OverallStatus
        End Get
        Set (value As Boolean)
            If _OverallStatus = value Then Exit Property
            _OverallStatus = value
            OnOverallStatusChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _OverallStatus As Boolean = False

    Protected Overridable Sub OnOverallStatusChanged(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent OverallStatusChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Event OverallStatusChanged As EventHandler
End Class
```

In VB, you can handle the event using the `WithEvents` and `Handles` keywords:

```
Class MyParent
    Private WithEvents myObject As New MyClass()

    Private Sub myobject_OverallStatusChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myObject.OverallStatusChanged
       ' TODO: Write handler.
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `OnOverallStatusChanged` function is useful for inheriting classes to get first shot at responding to the change.

```
Class MyOtherClass
    Inherits MyClass

    Protected Overrides Sub OnOverallStatusChanged(e As EventArgs)
        ' TODO: Do my stuff first.
        MyBase.OnOverallStatusChanged(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Use public properties instead of public variables. You can then put logic in the Set method of the property to execute whenever the property is.. well set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

```
Private number As Integer = 0
Public Property MyNumber As Integer
   ' Retrieves number.
   Get 
     Return number
   End Get
   ' Assigns to number.
   Set 
      CallLogicHere()
      number = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also define an event, which is fired each time the status changes. The advantage is, that changes can be handled by the parts of the application that depend on this status. Otherwise the logic would have to be implemented together with the status.

Other parts of the application can subscribe the event with `AddHandler`.

```
Public Class OverallStatusChangedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Sub New(newStatus As Boolean)
        Me.NewStatus = newStatus
    End Sub

    Private m_NewStatus As Boolean
    Public Property NewStatus() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_NewStatus
        End Get
        Private Set
            m_NewStatus = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Module modGlobals
    Public Event OverallStatusChanged As EventHandler(Of OverallStatusChangedEventArgs)

    Private m_boolOverallStatus As Boolean = True
    Public Property BoolOverallStatus() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_boolOverallStatus
        End Get
        Set
            If Value <> m_boolOverallStatus Then
                m_boolOverallStatus = Value
                OnOverallStatusChanged(Value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub OnOverallStatusChanged(newStatus As Boolean)
        RaiseEvent OverallStatusChanged(GetType(modGlobals), New OverallStatusChangedEventArgs(newStatus))
    End Sub
End Module
```